# How to convert an IList generic object to List<object>

Tags: c#, list, object

I want to pass in an unknown object to a method, and then let it return the object as a List. Basically, I want something like this

```
object b = new MyType();
object a = new List<MyType>()

public List<object> convertObjectBackToList(object Input)
{
    //if Input is an IList type (Ex: object a above)
    //return List<object>;

    //if Input is an generic object type. (Ex: object b above)
    //return an List<object> which has only one object.
    List<object> Output = new List<object>();
    Output.Add(Input);
    return Output;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast your object first to `IEnumerable`, then convert to list.

```
public List<object> convertObjectBackToList(object Input)
{
    if(Input is IEnumerable)
        return ((IEnumerable)Input).Cast<Object>().ToList();
    return new List<Object>() { Input };
}
```

**EDIT**

A generic extension method would even be better

```
public static partial class SOExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ToList2<T>(this object Input)
    {
        if (Input is IEnumerable)
            return ((IEnumerable)Input).Cast<T>().ToList();
        return new List<T>() { (T)Input };
    }
}
```

Then you could use it as

```
var list1 = someObject.ToList2<SomeType>();
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a master.